# preg_replace multiple times in same string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a text and I want to do something like Wiki code, creating links with [[]] and stuffs.

I am using this preg_replace to do that, and it seems to work:

```
<?=preg_replace("/\{\{([^\*]+)\|([^\*]+)\|([^\*]+)\}\}/", "<a href='$1.php#$2'>$3</a>", $conditions['pattern']); ?>
```

The problem is that when I have this text "can[not] build at %{{types|location|location}}% %{{some|other|stuff}}%" it outputs this:

```
can[not] build at %<a href="types|location|location}}% %{{some.php#other">stuff</a>%
```

It's like only the last one gets replaced, but wrong.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark the question as solved. To do that, just tick your answer by clicking the tick mark on the left. It should go green. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

I changed the regular expression to `/\{\{([a-zA-Z]+)\|([a-zA-Z]+)\|([a-zA-Z ]+)\}\}/` and now it works :D